# Why some bash function can't run in tmux?

Tags: shell, tmux

I have wrote some bash function in my `.bashrc`,it can work when i input it in terminal and click enter.
Now install tmux and reboot my pc.
Enter into tmux,i input the function's name and click enter in tmux:

```
command not found
```

I am wondering why the function can't work,how to make it work in tmux then?
Shell in my os:

```
awk -F: '{print $NF}' /etc/passwd |sort|uniq
/bin/bash
/bin/false
/bin/sh
/bin/sync
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: Does your `~/.bash_profile` source your `~/.bashrc` file? I _believe_ that `tmux` will start a login shell session, which means that `~/.bashrc` would not be sourced unless `~/.bash_profile` explicitly sources it.

Comment: `vim .bash_profile`, `source $HOME/.bashrc`